# print_config does not display values

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I am trying to debug some legacy UVM code and cannot figure out what is happening. Anyway, during my efforts, I came across this function, print_config(1), which should print out the config database recursively. For some reason, while I get the hierarchy, the printout does not show the values stored. I only get:

```
# resources that are visible in uvm_test_top.env.raster_stroke_agent.driver.sqr_pull_port
# vif [/^.*\.env\.raster_stroke_agent\..*$/] : ?
# -  
# th_testset_path [/^.*$/] : ?
# -  
# th_testset_name [/^.*$/] : ?
# -  
# th_testset_exp_path [/^.*$/] : ?
# -  
# th_number_of_images [/^.*$/] : ?
# -  
# th_cgs_red_lut_cfg_file_name [/^.*$/] : ?
# -  
# th_cgs_green_lut_cfg_file_name [/^.*$/] : ?
# -  
# th_cgs_blue_lut_cfg_file_name [/^.*$/] : ?
```

Why do I get the ? instead of actual values?

The basic problem I am having is while trying to read the field "testset_name", I get different values. This is how it is structured:

```
base test:       set_config_string ("*", testset_name, "ABC")
child test:      set_config_string ("*", testset_name, "JFK")
grandchild test: set_config_string ("*", testset_name, "XYZ")
```

Now when I try to access this variable from sequence, I get "ABC".
If I take out grandchild test "set_config_string", I get "JFK".

Shouldn't I be getting "XYZ"?

What is even more strange is the `print_config` printout:

```
# resources that are visible in uvm_test_top.env.raster_stroke_agent.driver
# vif [/^.*\.env\.raster_stroke_agent\..*$/] : ?
# -  
# th_testset_path [/^.*$/] : ?
# -  
# th_testset_name [/^.*$/] : ?
# -  
# th_testset_exp_path [/^.*$/] : ?
# -  
# th_number_of_images [/^.*$/] : ?
# -  
# testset_path [/^uvm_test_top\..*$/] : ?
# -  
# testset_name [/^uvm_test_top\..*$/] : ?
# -  
# testset_name [/^uvm_test_top\..*$/] : ?
```

Why are there 2 entries for testset name under the same component???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing there are 2 entries for testset_name because you do 2 set_config_string(..., "testset_name", ...) to that component.

This article https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/sysverilog/uvm/easier_uvm/configuration/ mentions that the call to set_config_* from the highest level of hierarchy wins. In your case both (or all 3) calls are at the same level of hierarchy, so I would assume that the last one wins. Last one means the one that is called last (it may be the case that in your child class you call set_config_* in your build phase, but in the base class you call it in end_of_elaboration phase; I assume the one from end_of_elaboration would win - explanation so we don't mix up the concepts of inheritance and order of calls). Also take care when the get_config_* is called, because if you set it again in end_of_elaboration, but get it in build, then the second set will not have any effect.

This paper http://www.verilab.com/files/configdb_dvcon2014.pdf is also pretty good in understanding the config DB. It suggests another way of debugging it by adding the plusarg +UVM_CONFIG_DB_TRACE to your simulator call. This will show you the exact order in which sets and gets happen, which might be more helpful than `print_config()`.

Comment: Using +UVM_CONFIG_DB_TRACE is also cleaner, because it doesn't require code modifications, like inserting calls to `print_config()`.

Comment: You say all 3 calls are from the same level of hierarchy. But they are set in base, child, and grandchild. So when you say that the highest level of hierarchy wins, then does that mean the base class setting would win?
I checked and they are all set in the build_phase.

Comment: Don't confuse class hierarchy (inheritance tree) with object hierarchy (instance tree).  What I meant was object hierarchy I.e. the setting from the parent object wins against the child object (test over env over agent - who instantates whom).